# How can I get UNIX timestamp of the start and and end of the day?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am struggling to be able to get start and end date values in UNIX format using Moment library.

I have tried the following:

```
  console.log(moment().startOf('day').format()); // works correctly - 2020-04-15T00:00:00+02:00

  console.log(moment().startOf('day').format('X')); // not what I need - 1586901600 = 04/14/2020 @ 10:00pm (UTC) (so minus 2h for the timezone)
```

So just to make sure I am sending correct time I did:

```
  console.log(moment.tz("2020-04-15T00:00" , "Europe/Warsaw").unix()); // again not what I need - 1586901600 = 04/14/2020 @ 10:00pm (UTC) (so minus 2h for the timezone)

  console.log(moment().startOf('day').utcOffset(moment().tz(process.env.TIMEZONE).startOf('day').format('x')).format('X')) // again not what I need - 1586901600 = 04/14/2020 @ 10:00pm (UTC) (even with UTC offset)
```

I read that you actually can not offset or timezone UNIX timestamp, that this is the same everywhere. Fine with me, however what would be the 'elegant way' of deducting the `"Europe/Warsaw"` automatically from the UNIX timestamp. Say for example that I have the timezone set in config file and I want JS to detect the offset based on the timezone and correctly deduct it from the UNIX timestamp.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: see  if this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript

Comment: Could you please tell us, whether your issue has been solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if I understand you correctly, but if you try to get **the unix timestamp of the start and end of a day in UTC**, that's the way to go:

```
const start = moment().utc().startOf('day').unix();
const end = moment().utc().endOf('day').unix();

console.log(start, end);
// 1586908800, 1586995199
```

**Note:** The output format is typeof number.